# Can I use WMI to find the network usage by each process?

Tags: networking, wmi, io, disk

I'd like to use WMI on some windows systems to poll the network usage of each process. From what I can tell, there are many IO instances in the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process but they are for the combined IO of network,disk,and device. Is there a way to break that up so I can get network and disk IO separate?

Comment: If you don't have to use WMI there are some possibilities defined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438240/monitor-a-processs-network-usage) (stackoverflow) to get the info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitor a process's network usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438240/monitor-a-processs-network-usage)