# Monitor a process's network usage?

Tags: c#, winapi, network-monitoring

Is there a way in C# or C/C++ & Win32 to monitor a certain process's network usage (Without that application being built by you obviously)? I would like to monitor just 1 process for like an hour or so, then return the bytes used by only that process, such as limewire for example.

Is it possible? I know netstat -e on windows will tell you total bytes sent/received, but that is for all processes.

edit: If i can't return just one processes usage, how can i get the bytes sent/received by the entire system? as netstat displays except i just want the integers.

eg:

```
netstat -e

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                    2111568926      1133174989
Unicast packets             3016480         2711006
Non-unicast packets            3122            1100
Discards                          0               0
Errors                            0               0
Unknown protocols                 0
```

I just want to get 2 variables, like rec = 2111568926 and sent = 1133174989

Comment: which one did you go for Mike?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) for this or write your own device driver. I don't think there are any per process perfmon counters you can leverage.

Answer (score 5):

[ 2021 edit: links are dead as the Network Monitor is discontinued after Windows XP. ]

It's possible, but if I'm not mistaken you'll have to create a network driver to filter all network traffic and than figure out which process created the traffic.

Microsoft has an free application for it called [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.2](http://blogs.technet.com/netmon/archive/2008/09/17/network-monitor-3-2-has-arrived.aspx) ([download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f4db40af-1e08-4a21-a26b-ec2f4dc4190d&DisplayLang=en)). According to the release notes it also has an api to use.

> Network Monitor API: Create your own
> applications that capture, parse and
> analyze network traffic!

[Here is a blog post about these API's](http://blogs.technet.com/netmon/archive/2008/10/29/intro-to-the-network-monitor-api.aspx).

In my opinion you should use this API (or another API such as WinPcap) to filter the traffic instead of writing your own device driver.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question on MSDN forum and get answer. Frankly speaking have tried it. I.e. tried but not so hard)) It was suggested to use ETW. I did not realize how to consume ETW events properly. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/perfmon/thread/b82da95a-1c18-49ce-9bfa-e3d79ec40907

Answer (score -1):

[NetLimiter 2 Limiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php)

[Network Traffic Monitor](http://www.nicocuppen.com/pit/editor/page_detail.php?id=10104)
You can get the last freeware version from [here](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/LFWV/NetworkTrafficMonitor.html)

Comment: Why are you -1 and leaving a comment on my answer. You should be putting this on the question.