# Network usage per application on windows 7

Tags: .net, wpf, networking, process

Currently I am searching a solution to get network usage per process on windows 7 but unfortunately I havn't found the solutuion or example under .net Framwork.

I used the GetTCPExtended() "ip helper" to getting the process who use the network and I hanv't idea how to do to get flow about each process like "Resources Mionitoring".

:)

Comment: Check out this SO answer: [Monitor a process's network usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438240/monitor-a-processs-network-usage/438277#438277)

Answer (score -1):

You have to override network adapter driver.