# How to get process network usage in Windows in python?

Tags: python, windows, bandwidth

I'm using Python 2.7 and Windows 7 (but I need it to work on at least XP as well).

How can I get the percentage of the network bandwidth used by my program written in Python? So if the internet speed is 20 Mbit/s, and my program is connecting to the web at a "full speed", it'd write 100%, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to develop a windows network driver with such capability.

Check the related answer at:
[Monitor a process's network usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438240/monitor-a-processs-network-usage)