# cpu usage ,memory , network details of each process running on windows machine using python

Tags: python

Hi Sorry I'm new to python. I'm not able to do this, I feel like it's easy but difficult to get the result so pls can anyone help me out this.

Here is my program and output (both actual and expected)

```
import os, platform, subprocess, re 
import sys
import psutil
import itertools 
import json
import procs

class BaseProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, name = "BaseProcessor"):
        self.name = name

    def processor(self):
        return self.proc

    def cpu_times(self):
        return self._base_cpu_times()

    def virtual_memory(self):
        return self._base_virtual_memory()

    def disk_io_counters(self):
        return self._base_disk_io_counters()

    def net_io_counters(self):
        return self._base_net_io_counters()

    def _init_proc(self):
        not_implemented

class PSUtilProcessor(BaseProcessor):
    def __init__(self, name = "PSUtilProcessor"):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.psutil = psutil
        self.proc = None
        if self._is_me():
            self._init_proc()

    def processor(self):
        return self.proc

    def _base_cpu_times(self):
        return { "overall" : self.psutil.cpu_times() }

    def _base_virtual_memory(self):
        return { "overall" : self.psutil.virtual_memory() }

    def _base_disk_io_counters(self):
        return { "overall" :  self.psutil.disk_io_counters() }

    def _base_net_io_counters(self):
        return { "overall" :  self.psutil.net_io_counters() }

    def _is_me(self):
        return platform.system() == self.name

    def _init_proc(self):
        not_implemented


class WinProcessor(PSUtilProcessor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Windows")

    def _init_proc(self):
        self.proc = platform.processor()

    def monitor(pid):
        cpu_table =[]
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        while p.is_running():
            cpu_table.append(p.get_cpu_percent())
            time.sleep(1)
        return cpu_table

class FileProcessor(BaseProcessor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Simulator")

    def monitor(pid):
        cpu_table =[]
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        while p.is_running():
            cpu_table.append(p.get_cpu_percent())
            time.sleep(1)
        return cpu_table

    def _base_cpu_times(self):
        rjson = { 'load from the file' }
        return rjson

class DarProcessor(PSUtilProcessor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Darwin")

    def _init_proc(self):
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + '/usr/sbin'
        command ="sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string"
        self.proc = subprocess.check_output(command).strip()

class LinProcessor(PSUtilProcessor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Linux")

    def _init_proc(self):
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + '/usr/sbin'
        command = "cat /proc/cpuinfo"
        all_info = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).strip()
        for line in all_info.split("\n"):
            if "model name" in line:
                self.proc = re.sub( ".*model name.*:", "", line,1)

# PFactory returns instance of an processor object based on the platform:

class PFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.objs = {}
        self.objs["Windows"] = WinProcessor()
        self.objs["Darwin"] = DarProcessor()
        self.objs["Linux"] = LinProcessor()

    def getMyProcessor(self):
        if platform.system() in self.objs:
           return self.objs[platform.system()]
        return BaseProcessor()

# PFactoryInstance creates an exact one instance of the PFActory object
# to get instance, you need to do the following:
#      PFactoryInst.getInstance()

class PFactoryInst:
    inst = PFactory()
    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        return PFactoryInst.inst



class pretty:
    def print(self, json_object):
        print(json.dumps(json_object, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

    def procc(self):
        proc = PFactoryInst.getInstance().getMyProcessor()
        return proc 

class process:
    def processcheck(self):
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            try:
                #pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name'])    
                pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid'])
                pinfo1 = proc.as_dict(attrs=[ 'name'])
            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                pass
            else:
                print(pinfo)
                #WinProcessor(PSUtilProcessor)
                processname = pinfo1['name'].split(".") [0] 
                print(processname)


if True:
                proc = pretty().procc()

                print("CPU times")
                pretty().print(proc.cpu_times())
                print("Virtual memory")
                pretty().print(proc.virtual_memory())
                print("disk_io_counters")
                pretty().print(proc.disk_io_counters())
                print("net_io_counters")
                pretty().print(proc.net_io_counters())

pretty.procc("system")
process.processcheck("system")
```

Actual output :

```
CPU times
{
    "overall": [
        5481.375,
        5862.203125,
        79719.484375,
        407.01564025878906,
        293.5625
    ]
}
Virtual memory
{
    "overall": [
        8459284480,
        4692054016,
        44.5,
        3767230464,
        4692054016
    ]
}
disk_io_counters
{
    "overall": [
        294267,
        282292,
        11056774144,
        7101620224,
        569959140,
        220317590
    ]
}
net_io_counters
{
    "overall": [
        3266163,
        31412196,
        14121,
        23535,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
{'pid': 0}
System Idle Process
{'pid': 4}
System
{'pid': 32}
SystemSettings
{'pid': 476}
winlogon
{'pid': 588}
smss
{'pid': 688}
svchost
{'pid': 744}
svchost
{'pid': 812}
csrss
{'pid': 908}
wininit
{'pid': 920}
csrss
{'pid': 984}
services
{'pid': 992}
lsass
{'pid': 1076}
dwm
{'pid': 1156}
svchost
{'pid': 1160}
svchost
{'pid': 1196}
svchost
{'pid': 1312}
svchost
{'pid': 1364}
EmsService
{'pid': 1372}
CMGShieldSvc
{'pid': 1380}
svchost
{'pid': 1484}
svchost
{'pid': 1508}
svchost
{'pid': 1552}
svchost
{'pid': 1640}
WUDFHost
{'pid': 1740}
igfxCUIService
{'pid': 1980}
SearchUI
{'pid': 2044}
RtkAudioService64
{'pid': 2064}
HidMonitorSvc
{'pid': 2104}
RAVBg64
{'pid': 2200}
mfevtps
{'pid': 2212}
enstart64
{'pid': 2220}
HipMgmt
{'pid': 2228}
VsTskMgr
{'pid': 2240}
cb
{'pid': 2256}
RAVBg64
{'pid': 2316}
FireSvc
{'pid': 2324}
ngvpnmgr
{'pid': 2452}
WUDFHost
{'pid': 2588}
jusched
{'pid': 2608}
o2flash
{'pid': 2852}
chrome
{'pid': 2864}
spoolsv
{'pid': 3052}
svchost
{'pid': 3060}
FrameworkService
{'pid': 3064}
svchost
{'pid': 3076}
mfemms
{'pid': 3108}
mqsvc
{'pid': 3116}
python
{'pid': 3196}
dasHost
{'pid': 3224}
chrome
{'pid': 3240}
sqlwriter
{'pid': 3280}
PFERemediation
{'pid': 3320}
notepad++
{'pid': 3324}
Titus
{'pid': 3352}
esif_uf
{'pid': 3372}
svchost
{'pid': 3384}
msdtc
{'pid': 3440}
vmms
{'pid': 3468}
ielowutil
{'pid': 3532}
chrome
{'pid': 3664}
mfevtps
{'pid': 3676}
GoogleCrashHandler64
{'pid': 3716}
mfeann
{'pid': 3988}
SearchProtocolHost
{'pid': 4076}
UcMapi
{'pid': 4132}
svchost
{'pid': 4436}
Titus
{'pid': 4444}
naPrdMgr
{'pid': 4476}
conhost
{'pid': 4520}
mfefire
{'pid': 4556}
UdaterUI
{'pid': 4628}
unsecapp
{'pid': 4736}
mcshield
{'pid': 5272}
PresentationFontCache
{'pid': 5280}
chrome
{'pid': 5380}
audiodg
{'pid': 5460}
Calculator
{'pid': 5608}
Apoint
{'pid': 5764}
taskhostw
{'pid': 5772}
esif_assist_64
{'pid': 5808}
sihost
{'pid': 5948}
cmd
{'pid': 6020}
WmiPrvSE
{'pid': 6112}
GoogleCrashHandler
{'pid': 6176}
explorer
{'pid': 6184}
CcmExec
{'pid': 6276}
NomadBranch
{'pid': 6300}
RtkNGUI64
{'pid': 6312}
chrome
{'pid': 6320}
unsecapp
{'pid': 6376}
chrome
{'pid': 6388}
WmiPrvSE
{'pid': 6408}
py
{'pid': 6500}
WmiPrvSE
{'pid': 6512}
WmiPrvSE
{'pid': 6524}
ApplicationFrameHost
{'pid': 6548}
McTray
{'pid': 6628}
igfxEM
{'pid': 6648}
RAVBg64
{'pid': 6704}
RuntimeBroker
{'pid': 6740}
igfxHK
{'pid': 6780}
igfxTray
{'pid': 6820}
SearchIndexer
{'pid': 6832}
chrome
{'pid': 7100}
CmRcService
{'pid': 7220}
DCCService
{'pid': 7304}
ApMsgFwd
{'pid': 7400}
ShellExperienceHost
{'pid': 7776}
ApntEx
{'pid': 7792}
chrome
{'pid': 7808}
conhost
{'pid': 7824}
hidfind
{'pid': 8068}
SCNotification
{'pid': 8084}
svchost
{'pid': 8128}
chrome
{'pid': 8132}
chrome
{'pid': 8216}
chrome
{'pid': 8244}
RAVBg64
{'pid': 8372}
svchost
{'pid': 8396}
jucheck
{'pid': 8444}
chrome
{'pid': 8448}
CmgSysTray
{'pid': 8572}
chrome
{'pid': 8708}
EmsServiceHelper
{'pid': 8780}
lync
{'pid': 8868}
OneDrive
{'pid': 8924}
StikyNot
{'pid': 9304}
lynchtmlconv
{'pid': 9676}
WmiPrvSE
{'pid': 9732}
chrome
{'pid': 9816}
SearchFilterHost
{'pid': 9976}
chrome
{'pid': 10032}
WmiPrvSE
{'pid': 10128}
chrome
{'pid': 10168}
conhost
{'pid': 11056}
chrome
```

Expected output:

I need to get the details of CPU, Memory and network I/O counter for each process (pid) running on the window machine (local system) but here we are getting overall CPU usage , memory details.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can monitor **cpu** and **memory usage** of individual process using python's **psutil** library. But for monitoring **network i/o** of individual process you will need to create a network driver for system which can filter the traffic for particular process. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438240/monitor-a-processs-network-usage)

Here's the solution for memory and cpu usage by process -

```
import psutil

# For Windows
process_data = {}
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print(proc.name())
    process_names[proc.name()] = {'cpu' : proc.cpu_percent(), 'memory': proc.memory_info()}

# For Linux
process_data = {}
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print(proc.name())
    process_names[proc.name()] = {'cpu' : proc.cpu_percent(), 'memory': proc.memory_full_info()}

print(process_data)
=> 
{
   'AGSService.exe': 
    {
        'cpu': 0.0,
        'memory': pmem(rss=8949760, vms=3072000, num_page_faults=2589, 
                  peak_wset=8994816, wset=8949760, peak_paged_pool=113696, 
                  paged_pool=111920, peak_nonpaged_pool=17296, 
                  nonpaged_pool=15080, pagefile=3072000,     
                  peak_pagefile=3244032, private=3072000)
     },
 ...}
```

Comment: :Thank you so much for spending time for my problem.. but what i'm getting is not wat i needed. can you please go through the code again

Comment: psutilprocessor class should be access by each process in the above program and print the details of cpu memory network., @Amey Dahale

Comment: Actually `process_data` is a dictionary for all the processes. I just posted the 1st process. The three dots (`...`) in dictionary indicates there are lot more items in dictionary. It was just for the sake of sample. Hope this helps

Comment: @SrustiManoj: You need to use the process id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984517/453673

Comment: For network usage per process, you can use scapy: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/make-a-network-usage-monitor-in-python