# Monitor an applications network traffic

Tags: python, windows, traffic

I'm looking for a way to monitor the network traffic coming from an application, specifically a steam game. The goal is to launch the game launcher, check to see if it's updating based on network traffic, then continue based on the results.

I'm not exactly sure where to start, so I haven't tried anything yet.

I'd like to check if it's updating, wait if it is, and move on once the launcher is finished updating.

Comment: that gets very OS specific, what platform are you using?

Comment: Ah sorry, Windows

Comment: sorry, I've not used windows for a few years…  have added a tag so others can find the question more easily

Comment: No worries, Thanks

Comment: that said, https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.connections potentially looks as though it might give you some info.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/438277/1358308 suggests that it used to be pretty difficult to get any more detail…

Comment: I looked over psutil. From what I can tell I am able to look at current connections but can't monitor the network activity of a specific program.