# How can I get the amount of data sent or received by a process on the windows platform?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, udp

I want to know the following information:
For each process on the windows platform:
pid sent received
... ...  ...

Are there some APIs that supply these information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Windows 7, popup `perfmon` for a quick look.  Also, consider this question:

[Can I use WMI to find the network usage by each process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/376541/175849)